# error after compilation

Tags: compiling, compilation-error

Why is this error occuring `I can't write on file "Boolean Algebra and Automata Theory.pdf"'. ...{\numberline {1.12}Boolean polynomial}{53}` after compilation?
I am using Miktex console version 2.9 and Texstudio editor.
My codes are:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{caption}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\begin{document}
    \title{Boolean Algebra and Automata Theory} 
    \author{Manjoy Das\\  email-id\\ contact number} % this line is marked red
    \date{}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
               text
    \clearpage
    \subsection{Boolean polynomial} %<--- the subsection in the error line as shown
               text
\end{document}
```

I added my contact number later. Before adding, it was all good.

Comment: Which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: Acrobat Reader DC

Comment: Did you by any chance open the PDF in Adobe Reader/Acrobat? That programme temporarily locks the PDF (as the programme can change the PDF) and thus you have to close the PDF from Adone before LaTeX can write to the PDF again.

Comment: Does it happen if the pdf is open somewhere and the compiler cannot compile if the pdf is open in adobe reader?

Comment: yes the pdf was opened in adobe reader.

Comment: Adobe is known to lock the file while it is open in Adobe. Other PDF viewers tend to now lock the file and thus does not have this issue. This is one of the reasons why we tend to recommend LaTeX editors that come with their own PDF viewer such that you don't have to close Adobe all the time

Comment: You can , put please don't add irrelevant questions into existing questions.

Comment: how do I use sumatra as pdf viewer?

Comment: You can configure your TeX editor to use SumatraPDF as the viewer you use (the way to do that depends on the editor), or declare it as the default pdfviewer (it has a menu item to open the current opened pdf in Adobe reader).

Comment: Which editor are you using? Most of the widely used LaTeX editors like texmaker, texstudio and texworks come with their own PDF viewer

Comment: @daleif as I mentioned in my question, I use Texstudio.

Comment: Then why do you use Adobe Reader to view the PDF and not the build in one? In texstudio you can even get the viewer to pop out of the editor.

Comment: @daleif Because sumatra is not installed in my computer. When I first installed protext rar file in computer, that file was corrupted. So I used adobe reader. After that I did not intend to go for sumatra.

Comment: Again I ask: since texstudio comes with its own build in PDF viewer, why do you need Adobe Reader or Sumatra? TexStudio has a button to pass the PDF on to a PDF viewer external to TeXStudio, but it also has its own PDF viewer. Additionally the build in PDF viewer comes with sync support so you can just from the code to the pdf and from the PDF to the code.

Comment: @daleif How do I enable that mode in Texstudio?

Comment: It is the default. So I don't know what you did to your texstudio. Under the normal settings if you run the tool `build and view` texstudio will preview the PDF in the build in viewer.